# cannot create zpool one or more vdevs refer to the same device, or one of the devices is part of an active md or lvm device""

Tags: zfs

I'm trying to create zfs pool on a new server. OS is CentOS 6.6. Kernel is 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64

By device letters:

zpool create -f data-pool raidz2  sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdi sdh cache sda -m /data

cannot create 'data-pool': one or more vdevs refer to the same device, or one of
the devices is part of an active md or lvm device

By disks path

```
zpool create -f data-pool raidz2 pci-0000:01:00.0-sas-0x50000c0f01f74eb2-lun-0 pci-0000:01:00.0-sas-0x50000c0f01f7538e-lun-0 pci-0000:01:00.0-sas-0x50000c0f01362b3e-lun-0 pci-0000:01:00.0-sas-0x50000c0f01f76726-lun-0 pci-0000:01:00.0-sas-0x50000c0f01f74eb3-lun-0 pci-0000:01:00.0-sas-0x50000c0f01f7538f-lun-0 pci-0000:01:00.0-sas-0x50000c0f01362b3f-lun-0 pci-0000:01:00.0-sas-0x50000c0f01f76727-lun-0 cache pci-0000:01:00.0-sas-0x5003048001a0092c-lun-0 -m /data
```

cannot create 'data-pool': one or more vdevs refer to the same device, or one of
the devices is part of an active md or lvm device

Output from lsblk:

```
lsblk 
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdj                             8:144  0  29.8G  0 disk 
├─sdj1                          8:145  0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sdj2                          8:146  0  29.3G  0 part 
  ├─vg_a140208-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0  26.4G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg_a140208-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0     3G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sda                             8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1                          8:1    0 119.2G  0 part 
└─sda9                          8:9    0     8M  0 part 
sdc                             8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sdc1                          8:33   0   3.7T  0 part 
└─sdc9                          8:41   0     8M  0 part 
sdh                             8:112  0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sdh1                          8:113  0   3.7T  0 part 
└─sdh9                          8:121  0     8M  0 part 
sdf                             8:80   0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sdf1                          8:81   0   3.7T  0 part 
└─sdf9                          8:89   0     8M  0 part 
sdi                             8:128  0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sdi1                          8:129  0   3.7T  0 part 
└─sdi9                          8:137  0     8M  0 part 
sdg                             8:96   0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sdg1                          8:97   0   3.7T  0 part 
└─sdg9                          8:105  0     8M  0 part 
sdd                             8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sdd1                          8:49   0   3.7T  0 part 
└─sdd9                          8:57   0     8M  0 part 
sdb                             8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sdb1                          8:17   0   3.7T  0 part 
└─sdb9                          8:25   0     8M  0 part 
sde                             8:64   0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sde1                          8:65   0   3.7T  0 part 
└─sde9                          8:73   0     8M  0 part
```

multipath is not installed

I don't see what can use my disks. Can anybody point me to a right direction?

I'd provide more info (fdisk output and /dev/disk/by-path/) but forum complains that it's too much code.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output of `dmsetup ls`?

Comment: Hi alvis! 

dmsetup ls
vg_a140208-lv_swap (253:1)
vg_a140208-lv_root (253:0)

Thanks!

Comment: Update:
When I list my disks bu id some of them are missing (sdb, sdc, sdh, sdi)
So I was able to create pool without these disks

`zpool create -f data-pool raidz2  sdd sde sdf sdg cache sda -m /data`

When I try to add these disks I get the following error:

`zpool add data-pool sdi -f
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/sdi1 is part of active pool 'data-pool'`

If I try to offline:
`zpool offline data-pool /dev/sdi1
cannot offline /dev/sdi1: no such device in pool`

Any ideas?

Comment: I checked my disks with the smartctl tool and I see the same serial and logical unit id for some hard disks. How is it possible?

 `smartctl -i /dev/sdd
Vendor:               WD      
Product:              WD4001FYYG-01SL3
Logical Unit id:      0x50000c0f01362b3c
Serial number:                WMC1F0D9FNER`

`smartctl -i /dev/sdh
Vendor:               WD      
Product:              WD4001FYYG-01SL3
Logical Unit id:      0x50000c0f01362b3c
Serial number:                WMC1F0D9FNER`

Comment: It means that the controller provides dual or multiple paths to the disks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused. So I have 8 disks, each 2 of them share the same serial number and I cannot create pool using all of them, only 4 with different serial numbers. I thought hard disk's serial numbers are manufactured to be unique. How can I fix this and create a pool using all 8 disks?

Comment: Are you sure you have 8 disks? From the output of `smartctl` it seems you have less and they are presented as individual disks for each path to the same disk. If you have access to the physical disks, can you verify that all 8 have different serial numbers? Can you also verify the connection isn't dual-path nor multi-path?

Comment: Can you also partition one disk and see if the other disk becomes partitioned as well? Copy a file and see if the other shows up with the same file?

Answer (score 0):

alvits!

You're right. I don't have access to this server, but there are apparently only 4 disks. Sorry for the noise. It's solved.